# how to inspect the output array from PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo()

Tags: 7, files

I got the following error message

```
PHPVideoToolkit Error: Execute error. Output for file "$DOCROOT/sites/example.com/files/private/videos/original/file.flv" was not found. Please check server write permissions and/or available codecs compiled with FFmpeg. You can check the encode decode availability by inspecting the output array from PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo().
```

How do I inspect the ouput array from `PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickest way I can think of:

- Install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel).
- Go to http://mysite.com/devel/php and run the following code:

  ```
  $info = PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo();
  dpm($info);
  ```

When you run that code you should be presented with a nicely formatted array in the messages area that you can inspect.

If you get an error that `PHPVideoToolkit` does not exist then find out what file in your installation declares that class, and make sure it's included using either [`module_load_include()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) or PHP's `include/require`.

Comment: When I execute `print Begin;
$info = PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo();
dpm($info);
print End;` only "Begin" is printed.  What does that indicate?

Comment: It would usually indicate that `PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo()` is returning `FALSE` or `NULL`. There seems to be a bit of a discussion about something similar [here](http://drupal.org/node/1325664), it might be worth a look